# Replace outgoing call screen in objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to override the default outgoing call screen with my own custom screen in objective C. I have tried it for last 2 days, but in all forum i was seeing negative answer like it was not possible in Objective C.
But i saw a app called Rebtel which achieved the same functionality of replacing the default outgoing call screen(in Local minutes mode). Could anyone here give an idea of how we do that?

I have also attached rebtel screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Is this app Rebtel on the AppStore? I could not find it.

I would say what you want is not possible without using any private API which will probably lead to a app rejection during AppStore QA phase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Here i have mentioned the AppStore link of Rebtel app  https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/cheap-international-calls/id310755560?mt=8

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Yes sure. In AppStore it named as Cheap International Calls & SMS | Rebtel. I also mentioned the AppStore link in above comment

Comment: I'd say that they don't replace the outgoing calls screen but rather provide a similar functionality.

Comment: @Paul : In that app call also connecting via sim carrier when the phone is in offline mode.So only i conformed that they replaced the outgoing call screen

Comment: Rebtel uses VOIP, no calling via the user SIM subscription. Yes it can call using WAN connection. When there is not internet connection they just start a call via an access number. They will first display there call screen then the app switches to the normal iOS dialer.

Comment: Looks like it is an VOIP app. It is not possible to replace the phone app on iOS. And never will be.

Comment: @rckoenes: In this app working fine in offline mode , I think it's not possible to make a call in offline mode using WAN or VOIP.

Comment: @Vignesh neither is it possible or allowed to replace the outgoing call screen. Even if Rebtel did this some how does not mean you will be able to do it. There is even a big chance that if you app gets rejected because you replaced the outgoing screen. Then if you say that Rebtel did this as well so you should be able to do it as Apple will pull the Rebtel app from the store.

Comment: @rckoenes: Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to replace the outgoing call screen, this could potentially create a privacy issues.

Also the app you mention is 100% voip app, I've installed the app turn off my WiFi and cellular data. And the app stop working:

[image]

If you have a internet connection an the choose not to user VOIP then the normal dialer is presented:
[image]

Comment: :To see that, tap on the small icon on the top right corner “Calls are connected using”, and pick the option of "Local minutes". 

When calling with the option "Local minutes" enabled, your call gets connected via our Access Number. This means that you will be charged by your local carrier the price of a local call (depending on your calling plan). The international part of the call is deducted from your Rebtel credit.

Comment: Then the call routed by to the native iOS dialer, so they do not replace the dialer when your not using VOIP.

Comment: Just for reference and clarification. Could you please attach the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks rckoenes for your valuable comments.